# NEO 6M doenst provide coordinates

Tags: arduino-leonardo, tinygps

I do a school project (CanSat) it's an international project. But my problem is my GPS. I tried 2 different codes. Both they say the GPS is connected. They GPS led doesn't provide any light.

wiring:
UBlox Neo 6M
Arduino leonardo
Rx (GPS) to port 8
Tx (GPS) to port 9
Vcc to Vcc
Gnd to Gnd

Btw I sit near the window.

First code:
The gps.encode(c) is always false/0 I don't know why this one doesn't work.

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(9, 8);
TinyGPS gps;

void gpsdump(TinyGPS &gps);
void printFloat(double f, int digits = 2);

void setup()  
{
  // Oploen serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("uBlox Neo 6M");
  Serial.print("Testing TinyGPS library v. "); Serial.println(TinyGPS::library_version());
  Serial.println("by Mikal Hart");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Sizeof(gpsobject) = "); 
  Serial.println(sizeof(TinyGPS));
  Serial.println(); 
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  bool newdata = false;
  unsigned long start = millis();
  // Every 5 seconds we print an update
  while (millis() - start < 5000) 
  {
    if (mySerial.available()){
      char c = mySerial.read();
     // Serial.println(c);  // uncomment to see raw GPS data
      if (gps.encode(c)){
        newdata = true;
        break;  // uncomment to print new data immediately!
      }
    }
  }

  if (newdata) 
  {
    Serial.println("Acquired Data");
    Serial.println("-------------");
    gpsdump(gps);
    Serial.println("-------------");
    Serial.println();
  }

}

void gpsdump(TinyGPS &gps)
{
  long lat, lon;
  float flat, flon;
  unsigned long age, date, time, chars;
  int year;
  byte month, day, hour, minute, second, hundredths;
  unsigned short sentences, failed;

  gps.get_position(&lat, &lon, &age);
  Serial.print("Lat/Long(10^-5 deg): "); Serial.print(lat); Serial.print(", "); Serial.print(lon); 
  Serial.print(" Fix age: "); Serial.print(age); Serial.println("ms.");

  // On Arduino, GPS characters may be lost during lengthy Serial.print()
  // On Teensy, Serial prints to USB, which has large output buffering and
  //   runs very fast, so it's not necessary to worry about missing 4800
  //   baud GPS characters.

  gps.f_get_position(&flat, &flon, &age);
  Serial.print("Lat/Long(float): "); printFloat(flat, 5); Serial.print(", "); printFloat(flon, 5);
    Serial.print(" Fix age: "); Serial.print(age); Serial.println("ms.");

  gps.get_datetime(&date, &time, &age);
  Serial.print("Date(ddmmyy): "); Serial.print(date); Serial.print(" Time(hhmmsscc): ");
    Serial.print(time);
  Serial.print(" Fix age: "); Serial.print(age); Serial.println("ms.");

  gps.crack_datetime(&year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second, &hundredths, &age);
  Serial.print("Date: "); Serial.print(static_cast<int>(month)); Serial.print("/"); 
    Serial.print(static_cast<int>(day)); Serial.print("/"); Serial.print(year);
  Serial.print("  Time: "); Serial.print(static_cast<int>(hour+8));  Serial.print(":"); //Serial.print("UTC +08:00 Malaysia");
    Serial.print(static_cast<int>(minute)); Serial.print(":"); Serial.print(static_cast<int>(second));
    Serial.print("."); Serial.print(static_cast<int>(hundredths)); Serial.print(" UTC +08:00 Malaysia");
  Serial.print("  Fix age: ");  Serial.print(age); Serial.println("ms.");

  Serial.print("Alt(cm): "); Serial.print(gps.altitude()); Serial.print(" Course(10^-2 deg): ");
    Serial.print(gps.course()); Serial.print(" Speed(10^-2 knots): "); Serial.println(gps.speed());
  Serial.print("Alt(float): "); printFloat(gps.f_altitude()); Serial.print(" Course(float): ");
    printFloat(gps.f_course()); Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Speed(knots): "); printFloat(gps.f_speed_knots()); Serial.print(" (mph): ");
    printFloat(gps.f_speed_mph());
  Serial.print(" (mps): "); printFloat(gps.f_speed_mps()); Serial.print(" (kmph): ");
    printFloat(gps.f_speed_kmph()); Serial.println();

  gps.stats(&chars, &sentences, &failed);
  Serial.print("Stats: characters: "); Serial.print(chars); Serial.print(" sentences: ");
    Serial.print(sentences); Serial.print(" failed checksum: "); Serial.println(failed);
}

void printFloat(double number, int digits)
{
  // Handle negative numbers
  if (number < 0.0) 
  {
     Serial.print('-');
     number = -number;
  }

  // Round correctly so that print(1.999, 2) prints as "2.00"
  double rounding = 0.5;
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<digits; ++i)
    rounding /= 10.0;

  number += rounding;

  // Extract the integer part of the number and print it
  unsigned long int_part = (unsigned long)number;
  double remainder = number - (double)int_part;
  Serial.print(int_part);

  // Print the decimal point, but only if there are digits beyond
  if (digits > 0)
    Serial.print("."); 

  // Extract digits from the remainder one at a time
  while (digits-- > 0) 
  {
    remainder *= 10.0;
    int toPrint = int(remainder);
    Serial.print(toPrint);
    remainder -= toPrint;
  }
}
```

Second code:
Location is invailed but i will get the time with an 1 hour and some minuts diffrence.

```cpp
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
/*
   This sample sketch demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS++ (TinyGPSPlus) object.
   It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
   4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 4(rx) and 3(tx).
*/
static const int RXPin = 9, TXPin = 8;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);

  Serial.println(F("DeviceExample.ino"));
  Serial.println(F("A simple demonstration of TinyGPS++ with an attached GPS module"));
  Serial.print(F("Testing TinyGPS++ library v. ")); Serial.println(TinyGPSPlus::libraryVersion());
  Serial.println(F("by Mikal Hart"));
  Serial.println();
}

void loop()
{
  // This sketch displays information every time a new sentence is correctly encoded.
  while (ss.available() > 0)
    if (gps.encode(ss.read()))
      displayInfo();

  if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10)
  {
    Serial.println(F("No GPS detected: check wiring."));
    while(true);
  }
}

void displayInfo()
{
  Serial.print(F("Location: ")); 
  if (gps.location.isValid())
  {
    Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
    Serial.print(F(","));
    Serial.print(gps.location.lng(), 6);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Date/Time: "));
  if (gps.date.isValid())
  {
    Serial.print(gps.date.month());
    Serial.print(F("/"));
    Serial.print(gps.date.day());
    Serial.print(F("/"));
    Serial.print(gps.date.year());
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.print(F(" "));
  if (gps.time.isValid())
  {
    if (gps.time.hour() < 10) Serial.print(F("0"));
    Serial.print(gps.time.hour());
    Serial.print(F(":"));
    if (gps.time.minute() < 10) Serial.print(F("0"));
    Serial.print(gps.time.minute());
    Serial.print(F(":"));
    if (gps.time.second() < 10) Serial.print(F("0"));
    Serial.print(gps.time.second());
    Serial.print(F("."));
    if (gps.time.centisecond() < 10) Serial.print(F("0"));
    Serial.print(gps.time.centisecond());
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.println();
}
```

another small weird thing is, that if I upload the code to the Arduino the Serial monitor says normally COM6(Arduino leonardo), but when it is just finished it goes to COM6 only but the program still works.

I will appreciate all the help I can get :)

Comment: Why use software serial if you have hardware serial available?

Comment: I don't know really the diffrence between Software serial and hardware serial if you can explain the diffrence when to use the one insteed of the otherone than would that be nice. But besides that it aren't my codes. I found the codes and I saw in the comments of that side that the codes worked.

the first code the gps.encode(c) is false, if I want the raw gps data I do Serial.println(c); where I get the raw gps date but it wouldn't encode so the code can proceed. So my question is there something wrong with the code or could there made an improving.

Comment: How about outside with clear sky?  Does the "They GPS led doesn't provide any light" indicate that the module isn't getting a fix?